# Powershell with GUI will not set variable

Tags: variables, user-interface, button, powershell

I am learning Powershell and attempting to create a GUI interface like the example [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730949.aspx).

However, when I run this as it is, `$x` is never defined. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? I know it has something to do with:

`$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()})`

Because if I change it to:

`$OKButton.Add_Click({Write-Host "worked";$objForm.Close()})`

It does return `worked`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your actionblock is running in a seperate local scope. To modify a global(session-wide) variable, use a scope-modifier(`$global:varname`). E.g.:

```
$OKButton.Add_Click({$global:x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()})
```

More about scopes at [Technet - about_Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) (or write `Get-Help about_scopes` in PowerShell)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$Global:variable` one can also use the `$Script:variable` which will increase the scope of your variable to your script. Hence, if you use A function to create buttons and within the function you also have the `.Add_Click({})` function, it will work within your function scope. 
The `$Script:` variable increase the scope of the variable to the nearest parent script file scope.